# How get ImageMagick filters dir

Tags: imagemagick

Some versions ago there was a command to get a `filters` (and `coders`) ImageMagick dirs:

```
MagickCore-config --filter-path
```

But now (I use 6.8.0 version) it seems there no such command anymore. This command give an error. Seems there no such option `--filter-path`.

So how should I get `filters` dir?

MagickCore-config is a script. It performs pkg-config calls. The content of /opt/local/lib/pkgconfig/ImageMagick.pc (there is no link to filters dir exists):

```
prefix=/opt/local
exec_prefix=${prefix}
libdir=${exec_prefix}/lib
includedir=${prefix}/include/ImageMagick

Name: ImageMagick
Description: ImageMagick - Convert, Edit, and Compose Images
Version: 6.8.0
Libs: -L${libdir} -lMagickCore
Cflags: -I${includedir}
```

I found filters dir manually on my system at `/opt/local/lib/ImageMagick-6.8.0/modules-Q16/filters`. But I need an automated way.

Answer (score 0):

The error was overpassed the next way:

According to http://www.imagemagick.org/script/resources.php there is a user-related dir for filters and coders: `$HOME/.magick`. So just use it in your scripts.

You need to set the following environment variable, actually:

```
export MAGICK_CODER_FILTER_PATH=$HOME/.magick/filters
```